# CakePHP Issue: Unexpected call to database

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

A question for the CakePHP community:

I am attempting to upgrade a website built using CakePHP 1.3.11 to CakePHP 2.0.4. It is a very simple site with no database attached, I wish to use the PagesController / PageModel  to validate the data passed to it from a Form and then send an E-Mail based on the information supplied.

The `$useTable` variable in `PageModel` has been set to false and the `database.php` `$default` is left as.. well, default (the reasoning being i dont need a database conneciton at anytime).

The problem comes in, when I try loading the view, i get:

> Error: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) requires a database connection.

Why would it give me this when at no time do i want a call to any database? Worked fine in 1.3.11, am I missing something...? Hope I explained the dilemma adequately. Any input would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you configure anything in your config/database.php ?

Comment: No, as stated the config/database.php has not been configured and the default connection array values are left blank. Why? For all intensive purposes lets assume there is no Database Server on the box, the website does not need a database and at no point do i call on a connection to the database. Surely CakePHP 2.0 caters for this scenario.

Comment: intents and purposes. sorry. bugs me :P

Answer (score 2):

It's slightly different for Cake 2.0 I believe; I've used this on a similar project:

In:

```
APP/Model/Datasource/Database/fake.php // fake.php is your class name

<?php
App::uses('DboSource', 'Model/Datasource');

// allows Cake to function without a database connection

class Fake extends DboSource {

public $description = "Disable the requirement of connecting to a database.";

function connect()
{
    $this->connected = true;
    return $this->connected;
}

function disconnect() // probably not necessary but for completion
{
    $this->connected = false;
    return !$this->connected;
}

}
```

and in `database.php`

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Fake', // usually Database/Mysql
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'user',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => '',
    'prefix' => '',
    'encoding' => 'utf8',
);

// I left the other keys in in case you need to swap
//   to a real connection quickly at some point.
```

this works in 2.0.4

Comment: I find it very strange that this is not catered for in CakePHP 2.0 as I would imagine it's a regular occurrence. Your solution however worked perfectly and I do thank you very much your input!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to create a dummy datasource if you are not using any database.

I have never done this, but this thread looks promising: http://groups.google.com/group/cake-php/browse_thread/thread/1254d64d4b21b24c

Comment: Thank you for your input, solution was provided here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8562288/1105939